# wipefs is not working as expected

Tags: linux, centos, partition

I am doing `wipefs -af /dev/sda1` and then creating pv but its throwing error

I am creating with command

```
pvcreate -qq --metadatasize=128M --dataalignment=256K '/dev/sda1'
```

and following is error

```
  [root@xxx]# pvcreate -qq --metadatasize=128M --dataalignment=256K '/dev/sda1'
  Can't open /dev/sda1 exclusively.  Mounted filesystem?
  Can't open /dev/sda1 exclusively.  Mounted filesystem?
```

After google i tried following options but still no success

```
[root@xxx]# pvremove /dev/sda1
  No PV found on device /dev/sda1.
```

I am running this on centos7.6

**Update1:**
After getting updates i tried following

```
[root@xxx]# umount /dev/sda1
umount: /dev/sda1: not mounted
```

To check which processes are accessing the device

```
fuser -m -v /dev/sda1
```

Comment: Im not quite sure why this is happening but i think you have to **unmount** /dev/sda1 first

Comment: It sounds like you 1) confirmed `/dev/sda1` is not mounted, 2) used `fuser` to check that no user process is accessing the device.  You could also check `lsblk` and see if you have any existing lvm/device-mapper/mdraid device as a subsidiary of `sda1`.  If you do, it will be indented and linked to `sda1`, in the same way that `sda1` is indented and linked as a subsidiary of `sda`.  (Or use `ls -l /sys/class/block/sda1/holders` )

Comment: Just a random guess, but ISTR LVM likes to have the system id set - https://serverfault.com/questions/519840/what-is-the-difference-between-the-linux-and-linux-lvm-partition-type

Comment: It's an old question - but primarily, there are four ways a disk/partition can be used: it's `mount`ed, it's used as `swap`, it's used as part of a logical volume, or it's used by `cryptsetup`.  Sometimes layered on each other.  Always check /proc/partitions to see how the disk is seen by the kernel, then /proc/mounts and /proc/swaps. LVs you can switch off by `vgchange -an`.  Logical volumes and cryptsetup volumes on top of disks could be  inspected by `dmsetup table`.  `dmsetup remove` and `cryptsetup close` can be used to close encrypted volumes.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a misunderstanding of some sort.

`pvcreate` is telling you that the device /dev/sda1 is still in use (this can be anything, for example it could still be mounted, or part of a RAID array, or device-mapped, or looped, or any running process like if you're in the middle of `dd` copying the device...).

`wipefs` would be telling you the same thing, if you didn't use `-f`

```
   -f, --force
          Force  erasure,  even if the filesystem is mounted.
```

If the device is still in use, that's a serious issue as whatever is using the device might modify data on the device. So you really should umount the device first (or otherwise make sure it's not in use anymore) before doing anything with `wipefs`, `pvcreate`, `mkfs` and the like.

`wipefs` at best only erases some magic bytes on the device, it does not solve any other problem for you, if it's still mounted you have to umount it yourself (or reboot and hope it won't be able to mount then), if it's still in use you'll have to find out what is still using it and why and then decide how to stop that.

Comment: i have updated my questions

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error when I used `wipefs` to clear out the bits to remove bcache. Even when I booted using a USB Ubuntu image, I found that it was still using `/dev/sda2` as swap.

I fixed it as follows:

1. I deactivated swap using

   ```
   swapoff /dev/sda2
   ```
2. Then, I reran

   ```
   wipefs --all --force /dev/sda*
   ```

   and it was able to remove the swap (and bcache) partitions `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sda3`.